# Insert current datetime based onclick

Tags: asp.net, database, datetime

I am currently trying to store datetime in the database. The idea is when onclick on the button, the database will store the current datetime in the database.
I have tried some methods but they prompt me with this error:

"Incorrect syntax near '26/6/2013 00:00:00'"

This is my codes:

```
con.Open();
        query = "INSERT INTO dbo.url_map (long_url, expiry_date) Values ('" + tbLongURL.Text + "' , '" + DateTime.Today + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@long_url", tbLongURL.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expiry_date", DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

what is wrong with the way i add the date time?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You missed comma after  '" + tbLongURL.Text + "'

Comment: what is the datatype of expiry_date field in sql server.

Comment: @Microsoft DJ.....nice catch...

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
The statement has been terminated.

This is what they prompt me after i add the comma. Sorry for the small mistake

Comment: sql server store datetime in datetime datatype

Comment: i set it as datetime datatype. but still the same error

Answer (score 3):

Corrected query-

```
   query = "INSERT INTO dbo.url_map (long_url, expiry_date) Values ('" + tbLongURL.Text + "', '" + DateTime.Today + "')";
```

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value. The statement has been terminated. This is what they prompt me after i add the comma

Comment: Try this...DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today(), "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); or DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

Comment: Provides information about a specific culture, which mean specific to local. Ex: US date format is different than the other country

Comment: for your first solution, cultureinfo does not exist in current context.

as for the second solution they show me the same out of range error

Comment: Try using 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' instead of simply 'CultureInfo'

Comment: Try this - DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: i've updated the codes. Please help me to see what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: You are just copying and pasting the solution everyone suggested instead of finding solution for yourself. Corrected line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expiry_date", DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Comment: Sorry but String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32404/discussion-between-microsoft-dj-and-qu3st)

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameters I think your query should be

```
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.url_map (long_url, expiry_date) Values (@long_url, @expiry_date)";
//this way sqlcommand make sense
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@long_url", tbLongURL.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expiry_date", DateTime.Today);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Insert();
    }
    public void Insert()
    {
        try
        {
            _conn = new SqlConnection(con);
            _cmd = new SqlCommand();
            _cmd.Connection = _conn;
            _conn.Open();
            _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            _cmd.CommandText = "insert_date";

            _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;


            _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }
```

Stored Procedure:

create procedure insert_date
@Date datetime
as
insert into DateTable values(@Date)

Result after insertion on table:

1   2013-06-26 14:29:36.987

Answer (score 0):

You can directly bind the Current Date to 'expiry_date' column in SQL server.

Steps:

1. Right click on your table and select 'Design'.
2. Click on the desired column, 'expiry_date' in your case.
3. In the column property, look for 'Default Value or Binding' in General Section.
4. Put 'GETDATE()' as the default value, so whenever you insert the record, it will take current date as its value.